# Laravel header logic

Tags: templates, laravel, laravel-blade

I am new to laravel and have a different header for logged in users.

I would like to know best practice for logged in user

would i do something like in my blade template

```
    @if(Auth::check())
            @include('header')
    @else {
           @include('header2')
             }
   @endif
```

Also is there a way to include this without all the @ signs?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with doing it this way, but you don't need the curly braces. The @ symbol is part of the blade templating engine and is how you do if statements, loops and includes it has nothing to do with the PHP error suppressor @

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks correct except "{" you do not need them in Blade Templating. In a further development it is possible that you will need more advanced verification system users, then move most of the functions to the controller.